# Can I catch an error from async without using await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, ecmascript-2016

Can errors from a non-awaited async call be caught, sent to an original encapsulating try/catch, or raise an uncaught exception?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
async function fn1() {
    console.log('executing fn1');
}

async function fn2() {
    console.log('executing fn2');
    throw new Error('from fn2');
}

async function test() {
    try {
        await fn1();
        fn2();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log('caught error inside test:', e);
    }
}

test();
```

In this scenario, the error thrown from `fn2` will be swallowed silently, and definitely not caught by the original `try/catch`. I believe this is expected behavior, since `fn2` is most likely being shoved off to the event loop to finish at some point in the future, and `test` doesn't care when it finishes (which is intentional).

Is there any way to ensure that errors are not accidentally swallowed by a structure like this, short of putting a `try/catch` internal to `fn2` and doing something like emitting an error? I would even settle for an uncaught error without knowing how to catch it, I think -- I don't expect thrown errors to be typical program flow with what I am writing, but swallowing errors makes it relatively annoying to debug.

Side note, I'm using Babel to transpile the code using the babel-runtime transform, and executing it with node.

Comment: Im not sure what are you trying to achieve, but would there be a reason not to use promises?

Comment: Use a promise library that supports unhandled rejection detection.

Comment: Tom, not really, no. I was intentionally using async/await over promises to see what could be done with es7 syntax at this point in time, and this was an issue I ran across while playing with it. Bergi, I'll definitely fall back to that if there are no other options at this time (which I suspect may be the case).

Comment: @dvlsg note that with Babel you have a bluebirdCoroutines transform that lets you use bluebird promises with native async/await.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dealing with unhandled rejected native promises (and async/await uses native promises) is a feature supported now in V8. It's used in the latest Chrome to output debugging information when a rejected promise is unhandled; try the following at [the Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/):

```
async function executor() {
  console.log("execute");
}

async function doStuff() {
  console.log("do stuff");
  throw new Error("omg");
}

function handleException() {
  console.error("Exception handled");
}

(async function() {
  try {
      await executor();
      doStuff();
  } catch(e) {
      handleException();
  }
})()
```

You see that, even though the exception from `doStuff()` is lost (because we're not using `await` when we call it), Chrome logs that a rejected promise was unhandled to the console:

[image: Screenshot]

This is also available in Node.js 4.0+, though it requires listening to [a special `unhandledRejection` event](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection):

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p) {
    console.log("Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ", p, " reason: ", reason);
    // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks for the links to the the github issues, I will keep an eye on those, and I'll swap to using io.js for the time being when testing what I'm working on.

Comment: Ah, one last caveat -- I had to add `process.on('unhandledRejection', err => { throw err; });` to get this to work as expected in io.js for now, based off of their [unit tests](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/blob/master/test/parallel/test-promises-unhandled-rejections.js#L86). Still a little hacky, but I am getting an error thrown with a (sort of) useful stack trace, this way.

Comment: Playing with this, it seems that an error thrown from an `async` function called without `await` cannot be caught. Is this the correct way of looking at it?

Comment: @Jehan That is correct. If you don't `await` it, the promise is created but will not throw. The new unhandled promise rejection mechanism in Chrome will catch it, however.

Comment: @dvlsg doing `process.on('unhandledRejection', err => { throw err; });` is definitely perfectly fine. Also note that since NodeJS and io.js are merging this feature can safely be used as it will land in Node on convergence.

Comment: Just as a follow up, now that Node 4.0 is out, I can confirm that `process.on('unhandledRejection', err => { /* ... stuff */ });` works as expected after the iojs merge, and is still necessary to prevent accidentally swallowing uncaught rejections (as opposed to the behavior in Chrome).

Comment: @MichelleTilley In your example, the console doesn't show the message "Exception handled", which leads me to believe that the error doesn't get handled by your try-catch.

Comment: @trusktr That's the point; `try`/`catch` around async functions only works when you `await` the function call. Said another way, `await`ing a rejected promises turns it into an exception, but *only* if you `await` it. The point the example is that Chrome has a mechanism built-in for when you accidentally screw this up. :)

Comment: Does this mean unhandled exceptions mapped to the promise rejection as well?  So if I were mixing promises and async/await I could do doStuff().catch(error => handleException()) ?

Answer (score -11):

If you are familiar with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), use them. If not, you can try this example to make you code more asynchronous :)

```
function fn1(callback) {
    console.log('executing fn1');
    callback({status: true});
}

function fn2(callback) {
    console.log('executing fn2');
    callback({status: false});
}

function test() {
    fn1(function(result) {
        console.log('fn1 executed with status ' + result.status);
    });

    fn2(function(result) {
        console.log('fn2 executed with status ' + result.status);
        if (result.status == false) {
            console.log('error in fn2');
        }
    });
}

test();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am intentionally using ES7 async/await in this scenario, though. I know, I'm being stubborn, and I'm using features which aren't even fully accepted yet, but they improve the syntax and readability of my actual code significantly (it involves long/infinite while loops inside `async` functions with `await` inside the loops).