# cannot catch error in function called inside try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I'm having trouble with some asynchronous functions in a nodejs server. This is the first time that I deal with try/catch blocks and I cannot catch the error inside the called function.

my code:

```
calledFunction: async function() {
    try{
      //DO SOMETHING THAT RETURNS AN ERROR
    }
    catch(error) {
      //NEED TO CATCH THIS ERROR IN mainFunction()
      var error = {};
      error.error = err.message;
      return error;
    }
}

mainFunction: async function () {
    try {
      await this.calledFunction();
      return true;
    }
    catch(error) {
      var error = {};
      error.error = err.message;
      return error
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to do `catch(err) {` for it to work, or else this statement `err.message;` will generate an error of its own.

Comment: This looks related, maybe it's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649994/can-i-catch-an-error-from-async-without-using-await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethrow the error in your catch block.

```
try{
  //DO SOMETHING THAT RETURNS AN ERROR
}
catch(error) {
  //NEED TO CATCH THIS ERROR IN mainFunction()
  var error = {};
  error.error = err.message;
  throw error; // Rethrow
}
```

My blog has [more info on using async/await with try/catch](http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html) if you want to learn more.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I tried your solution but its not working. I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when `calledFunction()` runs